# How to make absolute positioned element to don't show scrollbars in the parent?

Tags: html, css, overflow, absolute

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;

}

.child-green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.child-blue {
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-green'></div>
  <div class='child-blue'></div>
</div>
```

Code example: https://codepen.io/asad111/pen/jOPqpaj

All elements must be in this location but no horizontal scroll bar for the green element (of course this can't be just overflow-x hidden or a hack like that)

[image]

**I can't take the `overflow: auto` from the parent, otherwise it will not scroll for elements in the flow.** For example the blue box needs to force the parent to scroll.

**Note: I really need the child to go out the parent bounds** I'm doing an animation of things moving on the screen and needs to go edge to edge.

So the question is, why position absolute element, that is not supposed to take space... well, takes space? And how can I fix it?

One solution is to wrap again:

https://codepen.io/asad111/pen/jOPqvYV

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child-green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.child-blue {
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-wrapper'>
    <div class='child-green'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='child-blue'></div>
</div>
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the child element has left 250px + width 100px, so together there is 350px in parent which is 300px wide, that's why it shows the scrollbar. 
Make it left 200px, then the scrollbar will dissapear.

Comment: I need the child to go out of the parent... but how the width is calculated if the position absolute doesnt take width?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: I need the child to go out of the parent bounds

Comment: can you share the screenshot for rough idea.

Comment: https://codepen.io/asad111/pen/jOPqpaj - needs to be without horizontal scroll

Comment: try This

overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: no, cant do with that. This is just one case scenario. sometimes it might overflow y. Has to handle both scenarios...